# Calling isinstance in main Python module

Tags: python

There is a strange behavior of isinstance if used in `__main__` space.

Consider the following code

a.py:

```
class A(object):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from b import B
    b = B()
    print(isinstance(b, A))
```

b.py

```
from a import A
class B(A):
    pass
```

main.py

```
from a import A
from b import B

b = B()
print(isinstance(b, A))
```

When I run `main.py`, I get `True`, as expected, but when I run `a.py`, I am getting `False`. It looks like the name of `A` is getting the prefix `__main__` there.

How can I get a consistent behavior?
I need this trick with import of `B` in `a.py` to run `doctest` on file `a.py`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WSo what happens when you run `a.py` is that Python reads `a.py` and executes it. While doing so, it imports module `b`, which imports module `a`, but it does not reuse the definitions from parsing it earlier. So now you have two copies of the definitions inside `a.py`, known as modules `__main__` and `a` and thus different `__main__.A` and `a.A`.

In general you should avoid importing modules that you are executing as well. Rather you can create a new file for running doctests and use something like

```
import a
import doctest

doctest.testmod(a)
```

and remove the `__main__` part from module `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Chain of events:

1. The a.py script is called.
2. The `class A` statement is executed, creating `A` in the `__main__`
   namespace.
3. `b` is imported.
4. In b.py `a` is imported.
5. The `class A` statement is executed, creating `A` in the `a` namespace.
   This `A` in the `a` namespace has no relation to the `A` in the
   `__main__` namespace other than having been generated by the same
   code. They are different objects.

---

I agree with Helmut that it is best to avoid such circular imports. However, if you wish to fix your code with minimal changes, you could do the following:

Let's rename `b.py` --> `bmodule.py` so we can distinguish `b` the module from `b` the variable (hopefully in your real code these names are already distinct):

```
class A(object):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import bmodule
    b = bmodule.B()
    print(isinstance(b, bmodule.A))
```

prints

```
True
```